# Performing an Archive in Xcode with an iPad 4 connected

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I used Xcode to Archive my application; but once I exported an IPA, I found that I couldn't get the IPA to install on any iPad using IPCU (I get a "This application **does** support this device's CPU type" message).

After some investigation, I found that this happens when I have an iPad 4 plugged in to my machine; but does not happen otherwise. Presumably this is because Xcode is changing the Architectures in my Build Settings to match the connected device?

**Is there a way that I can configure Xcode, so I can create an archive to be installed on any iPad (1/2/3/4) while I have an iPad 4 connected?**

Comment: Im doing a lot of builds every day for various apps and often experienced a similar issue - that, although all the profiles were correct, the devices were provisioned, but still kept getting errors. This post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18408773/1218015 about using Apple Configurator to get a detailed error information helped to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing ARV7S from valid architectures under build setitng

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working now.
Would I be better to change the Architectures rather than the Valid Architectures? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701188/whats-the-difference-between-architectures-and-valid-architectures-in-xcode)

Comment: I can give you only one hint. You are using some library that is not update for Apple's new architecture ARV7S, i.e. iPhone5 and iPad4.

Comment: The app does run on an iPad 4 though, it's just the archive that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In build settings is ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH set to No? (it should)

Comment: Yes, it is currently set to NO.